# What is Mangal Dosh (Mangalik)

Tags: belief

Meaning of the words used :

- Kundali - Horoscope
- Mangal - Planet Mars
- Peepal Tree - Ficus religiosa or Sacred Fig
- Dosh - Blame

Indian people often match Kundalis before they allow the boy and the girl to marry. The most often thing I always mark is that they see whether a boy or a girl is mangalik or not so why they need to see that?

I've heard people saying that if an individual has mangal dosh in his kundali, he suffers from tensions in his relationship, unfavorable for marriages and also, ones life can end.

Moreover, they are resolved by doing a *Kumbh Vivah* i.e a mangalik first marries a Banyan tree or a Peepal tree, or they are married to Gold or Silver idol of lord Vishnu.

So coming to the point, what is Mangalik *(Mangal Dosh)* and why they marry a tree before they marry a real person?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the *lagna kundali* (birth chart with the ascedant) of a person if any malefic planet (especially the planet mars) is present at least in the lagna (1st house) or in the 7th house (house of the spouse or marriage) then the person is considered to be a *mangalik*. Other houses that are considered for mars's presence for a person to be *mangalik* are 2nd, 4th, 8th and 12th.

> If Mars be posited there,  she will become a widow, both benefics and
>   malefics occupy the 7th house, she  will   remarry.   If   there be a
>   malefic or  malefics  in  the 8th house,  she will  get  a  shortlived
>   husband. If the 2nd house is occupied by malefics, the native dies
>   with  her husband. [Phaladipika, Chapter 11]

Mars being firey in nature when it looks upon the house of marriage or partner, it is said to burn that house. Hence, it creates tension, quarrel, etc. among the partners and even affects the health and life of the spouse of a *mangalik* person. So if one of the partners has  *magalik dosh* marriage is discouraged. If both partners have the fault, then it gets canceled  out and marriage is ok.

However, sometimes Kumbh Vivah is performed because it makes the banayan tree, peel tree, etc. the first husband and then it has to suffer the bad consequences of the mangalik dosh, not the actual husband. Vishnu being God  Himself, it is believed mars can't have -ve effects on Him.

*Disclaimer:  I have provided the answer only as per my awareness about astrology, I am not an expert.*

Answer (score 2):

If a person has Mars in the 1st, 2nd, 4th, 7th, 8th or 12th house, the person is Manglik. Although, unnecessary importance should not be given to such concepts as they are limited in scope:

> Vedic astrology is known for its negative readings in the West. As in
>   India so in the West primarily to entice clients and earn from
>   remedial measures. Mangal dosha is one of the most misused concepts by
>   astrologers to make money and promote fear. In Bharatiya Vidya Bhavan
>   we stress on the totality of a horoscope which has to have different
>   shades of happiness and unhappiness, materialism and spirituality; the
>   modern and ancient meaning.

The above is an excerpt from an article by Deepak Bisaria, editor at the *Journal of Astrology*

http://www.journalofastrology.com/article.php?article_id=310

Also, I would like to point out that 5 out of the 12 houses are considered for being a Manglik. This means that mathematically *40%* of the world's population in Manglik.

Answer (score 2):

Mars is a red planet and the shading red symbolizes animosity, enrages and manliness. Planet Mars rules mettle, certainty, enthusiasm, assurance, aspiration and consolation. It urges us to face challenges and to be our best. Affirmation and a challenging, intrepid nature satisfy this planet.

Mars, the God of War, is the leader of Aries. In astrology, Mars is the planet of vitality, activity, and craving. It is the survival sense, and can be considered as the "remaining" creature nature of man. Mars in Ascendant makes a man look youthful. It controls enthusiasm and shows solid and wild sexual desire.

Mars play a very important role in marriage of a girl and boy. The ‘defect or dosh’ created by planetary position of Mars is known as Mangal Dosha. Mangal dosha is completely based on the planetary status. According to Vedic Astrology birth cycle of a born if Mangal is present in 1st , 4th , 7th , 8th  and 12th  house, then such a situation is called the 'natives born Manglik'. This condition is considered extremely inauspicious for marriage, stress and disarray in relationship, unusual and unpleasant incident, constraints and discomfort in work, at home and any kind of inexplicably damage and problems caused by the fault of accelerated Asamayik of death. According to astrology, a Manglik girl or boy should marry another Manglik. If the bride and groom both have Mangal dosha yoga, then it gets cancelled out or eliminated. Basically, according to the nature of the planet Mars, this yoga is harmful, but with certain vedic rituals and methods effects could be easily reduced.

**How we can diminish the Effect of Mars or Mangal Dosha**

- The red coral gemstone is controlled via planet Mars. Red coral decreases the impact of Mangalik Dosha and bring concordance amongst a couple and enhances the relationship. It controls the imprudence and rankles.
- As said above, if both accomplices are Manglik then this gets invalidated and all the awful impacts gets offset.
- Mangal Pooja(Bhat Pooja) or Ritual in Mangal Nath Temple : Managl Nath Temple is arranged in Holy City Ujjain on Mangal Nath street on the bank of River Shipra and arranged on the land line of 'Tropic of Cancer'. The Mangal pooja is performed by savants and if performed for Mangal Shanti.
- Fasting on Tuesday – It is likewise a compelling solution for lessen the impact of Mangal in Kundali.
- Offer sustenance to creatures winged creatures and poor ones on Tuesday.

[Read More](https://www.gemsratna.com/red-coral-can-diminish-the-effect-of-mars-or-mangal-dosha-benefits-and-uses-of-red-coral)